# Getting Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tslint

I'm working on a big `React + TypeScript` project.

It works well on the local machine of other colleagues, but on mine I get the following error:

```
Line 1:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
```

as you can see below:

[image]

Here is the source code:

```
export type LoadOfferType = typeof import("../offers/defaultOffer");

export const loadOffer = async (): Promise<LoadOfferType> => {
  const offerName = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? process.env.REACT_APP_FALLBACK_SITE : "defaultOffer";

  /**
   * We use a switch statement instead of ane xpression for the offer path
   * because Webpack throws a critical dependency error when using paths
   * that are not explicitly defined.
   */
  switch (offerName) {
    case "mysite.com":
      return await import("../offers/mysite.com");
    default:
      return await import("../offers/defaultOffer");
  }
};
```

The commands I ran after cloning the repository were:

```
$ yarn install
$ yarn start
```

Here there is some info about my system:

```
$ node -v
v12.13.0

$ npm -v
6.12.0

$ yarn -v
1.19.1
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste the content of `"../offer/defaultOffer"`?

Comment: Why are you using a dynamic import when it's at the top of the file and seems like it will always get loaded? Why not do `export type LoadOfferType = typeof require("../offers/defaultOffer");`?

Comment: It's also possible that you aren't on the right version of TypeScript. Dynamic imports were added in v2.4

Comment: And you need to have `"module": "esnext"` in your configuration

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things could be happening. Have you created a ts.config.js with ts configuration and parser config, something like:

```
 export const typescriptConfig = {
 extends: ['plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint- 
 recommended'],
 overrides: [
   {
     parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
     extends: [
       'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
       'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
       'plugin:import/typescript',
     ],
     plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],

     files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],

     rules: {},
   },
 ],
```

}

Create React App uses ESLint by default. However, ESLint can't parse TypeScript by default. If you want, you may consider using @typescript-eslint/parser.

This could be that the base babel-eslint parser not working correctly without any config.
ESLint is not applying different parsers to different files, hence babel-eslint might be throwing an error.

Make sure your config file is created in the root of the project. I would start with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on an old version of TypeScript. Your syntax is perfectly valid.

## Tested

Example test done locally. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up here because I accidentally was doing

```
{
  items ?? [],
}
```

when I should have been doing

```
{
  items: items ?? [],
}
```